# XPath filter not working on XSL

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people><human><sex>male</sex><naxme>Juanito</naxme>
</human>
<human><sex>female</sex><naxme>Petra</naxme></human>
<human><sex>male</sex><naxme>Anaximandro</naxme></human>
</people>
```

and this XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/people/human[sex='male']">

        <xsl:value-of select="naxme"/>
         </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm expecting it to filter out the female, and it kind of works but I get odd values for the non-matching nodes:

```
Juanito
femalePetra
Anaximandro
```

I'm expecting the same output as with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/people/human">
<xsl:if test = "sex='male'">
        <xsl:value-of select="naxme"/>
</xsl:if>         </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll expand on Daniels answer which covers a little of the why.

The reason you are getting two different outputs comes down to the [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule), and how nodes and text are treated by default.

Summarising that link, if no other template exists, there are default templates that ensure every node - be it element, text, attribute, comment - will be encoutered, just to ensure that other nodes that do have rules can be processed correctly.

With this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/people/human[sex='male']">
        <xsl:value-of select="naxme"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you have an explicit rule that says:

> If you find a node that matches the XPath `/people/human[sex='male]` do this template.

Along with the default rule:

> Find all nodes, and then process all of their children. If it is text, just output the text.

This default rule is why your template is being processed, since you have no explicit rule for the root node - `/` - it any every child and grandchild node are processed using the default rules, unless another exists. As such, each node is traversed using the defaults, *except for the nodes matching `/people/human[sex='male]`*. The result of this is that when you have a node that is "female" the text is being spat out instead of ignored.

However, contrast this with:

```
<xsl:template match="/people/human">
    <xsl:if test = "sex='male'">
        <xsl:value-of select="naxme"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Where the rule becomes:

> If you find a node that matches the XPath `/people/human` do this template.

It just so happens that in that template, you have an extra condition that says, if it is male, then process it in some way, with no other conditions, so if a "female" node is encountered it is now blank in the output.

Lastly, *the reason why Daniels answer works but could easily break*, is that it changes the rule for processing text. Instead of now copying all text as in the default rules, it outputs nothing (as per the empty template. **However, if you had any other templates which used `xsl:apply-templates` to process text and were expecting text, *they would also now output nothing.***

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted this answer: it's a careful and helpful response. Upvoting to cancel this out!

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because of XSLT's [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule). Try adding this template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it works! can you please elaborate a bit on why this happens? By adding this template, does one override some default behavior?

Comment: @Slash - Yes you're overriding the default behavior. Read more here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule

Comment: -1 techincally correct, but if the OP had any `apply-templates` that relied on the default behaviour when processing text, they'd now break.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - Yes *if* the OP relied on default behavior this template would override it and "break" the stylesheet. However, the OP does not. I supplied the link explaining the default behavior so the OP would understand how it works. This would prevent the OP from "breaking" future stylesheets. I don't see how my answer deserves a downvote (defined as "This answer is not useful.").

Comment: Its nothing personal. However you said "probably" without explaining why the two different approaches the OP took were different. You didn't explain why you answer worked. You didn't explain what might happen with the change you suggestsed, which would probably lead to the OP asking more questions, because they didn't understand why this answer worked.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - I didn't take it personally. I said "probably" because I didn't have time to test. This was one of those "I have a .5 minute; I can post something basic to help." type of answers. I still disagree with the downvote, but I'm not worried about it. :-) It was good of you to add a more detailed answer. (I didn't downvote btw.)